# Common Math NoBracketingException on solving the equation

Tags: java, exception, equation, solver

I have a class I created on yield to maturity calculation and I use BrentSolver() in common math to solve equations, but I got an exception when I tried to change my code.

```java
double lowerBound = 0.000;
double upperBound = 35.000;
double initialGuess = 0.01;

UnivariateFunction ytmFunction = new UnivariateFunction() {
    @Override
    public double value(double ytm) {
        double presentValue = 0.0;
        int index = 1;
        
        for (Map.Entry<Double, Double> entry : series.getCashFlow().entrySet()) { // iterate cashflow.size times
            double time = entry.getKey();
            double cashFlow = entry.getValue();
            
            if (cashFlow > faceValue) {
                cashFlow = cashFlow - faceValue;
                presentValue += (cashFlow/paymentFrequency) / Math.pow(1 + ytm/paymentFrequency, index); //numberOfPayments
                continue; // Skip the current iteration and move to the next one
            }
            
            presentValue += (cashFlow/paymentFrequency) / Math.pow(1 + ytm/paymentFrequency, index);
            index++;
        }
        presentValue += faceValue / Math.pow(1 + ytm/paymentFrequency, numOfPayments); // numOfPayments or maturity???
        return savedPrice - presentValue;
    }
};

UnivariateSolver solver = new BrentSolver(); 
double ytm = solver.solve(10000, ytmFunction, lowerBound, upperBound, initialGuess);
return ytm;
```

I wanted to remove what I thought were unnecessary code blocks because I already have a value in my cashFlow map with faceValue+couponPayment, so I simplified the code:

```java
double lowerBound = 0.000;
double upperBound = 35.000;
double initialGuess = 0.01;

UnivariateFunction ytmFunction = new UnivariateFunction() {
    @Override
    public double value(double ytm) {
        double presentValue = 0.0;
        int index = 1;
        
        for (Map.Entry<Double, Double> entry : series.getCashFlow().entrySet()) { // iterate cashflow.size times
            double time = entry.getKey();
            double cashFlow = entry.getValue();
            presentValue += (cashFlow/paymentFrequency) / Math.pow(1 + ytm/paymentFrequency, index);
            index++;
        }
        return savedPrice - presentValue;
    }
};

UnivariateSolver solver = new BrentSolver(); 
double ytm = solver.solve(10000, ytmFunction, lowerBound, upperBound, initialGuess);
return ytm;
```

This way some ytm values ​​are printed but at one point I got the following error:

```java
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.commons.math3.exception.NoBracketingException:
    function values at endpoints do not have different signs, endpoints: [0, 35],
    values: [39.877, 96.209]
    at org.apache.commons.math3.analysis.solvers.BrentSolver.doSolve(BrentSolver.java:132)
    at org.apache.commons.math3.analysis.solvers.BaseAbstractUnivariateSolver.solve(BaseAbstractUnivariateSolver.java:199)
```

Even I didn't change any value, the code is supposed to work the same, what could be the error here?